# python name error name not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the error name not defined on running this code in python3:

```
def main():
    D = {} #create empty dictionary
    for x in open('wvtc_data.txt'):
        key, name, email, record = x.strip().split(':')
        key = int(key) #convert key from string to integer
        D[key] = {} #initialize key value with empty dictionary
        D[key]['name'] = name
        D[key]['email'] = email
        D[key]['record'] = record

print(D[106]['name'])
print(D[110]['email'])
main()
```

Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the dictionary was populated with key = 106 and 110 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `D` is local to the function `main`, and, naturally, the code outside does not see it (you even try to access it *before* running `main`). Do something like

```
def main():
    D = {} #create empty dictionary
    for x in open('wvtc_data.txt'):
        key, name, email, record = x.strip().split(':')
        key = int(key) #convert key from string to integer
        D[key] = {} #initialize key value with empty dictionary
        D[key]['name'] = name
        D[key]['email'] = email
        D[key]['record'] = record
    return D

D = main()
print(D[106]['name'])
print(D[110]['email'])
```

Comment: how can i make D available so it can be accessed by other functions created in the program?

Comment: By returning it from the function, as seen here, and passing it to other functions that need it.

Comment: Make it global, that is define it outside all the functions. It will be accessible anywhere from this module (use [``global``](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) if you want to reassign it inside a function).

Comment: @Bogdan I can't disagree with that suggestion more.  Making global variables in python is rarely the best method... passing the variable around is much clearer and removes difficult to debug scope errors.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, it was the answer to his question. I agree that having and, especially, changing a global variable is a bad practice most of the time, but we can't really pretend that global variables do not exist in Python. Spaghetti code is one of the things you have to experience before you understand why it's bad.