# python error name not defined

Tags: python

I am following https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/12/image-processing-python-basics/ to practice image processing.

I am writing the code in an incremental way and checking if everything goes well. So far I have written the following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import blob_dog, blob_log, blob_doh
from math import sqrt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import glob
from skimage.io import imread

example_file=glob.glob(r"/home/snowbell/sample.jpg")[0]
im=imread(example_file, as_grey=True)
plt.imshow(im, cmap=cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

The image location and the image name is only thing I have changed. I am getting the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    plt.imshow(im, cmap=cm.gray)
NameError: name 'cm' is not defined
```

Comment: Just a note : this looks more like a programming question rather than something Unix-related. PS: A simple google search after your NameError would yield lots of helpful results.

Comment: What did you expect `cm.gray` to produce? You never defined the name `cm` nor did you import it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python name error name not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285014/python-name-error-name-not-defined)

Answer (score 10):

`from matplotlib import cm` should work. Or `import matplotlib.cm as cm`